# How can i change item value in onItemAdd event ? - Selectize.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js for tags. I want to add new tag dynamicly on my select. When i add new item to my db with ajax request in onItemAdd event, this option has no right value. How can i change value of item when ajax is done ?

My code :

```
$('.campaign-tag-selectize').selectize({
            plugins         : ['remove_button', 'restore_on_backspace'],
            create          : true,
            onItemAdd : function (value, $item) {
                if(!Number.isInteger(value)){
                    $.post('/ajaxrequesturl', {'title':value, "_token": $('input[name="_token"]').val()}, function (returnVal) {
                        // I try to change value with change attr but not working :)
                        $item.attr('data-value', returnVal.id);
                        console.log(returnVal);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```